# Python Pandas - Combining specific tabs in multiple spreadsheets into one

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have Multiple spreadsheets each of which contains multiple tabs within them.  A common factor is that each of the spreadsheets has a tab containing the raw data but the tab names are all different in each of the files.   The raw data tabs have the exact same columns (in some cases in different orders).

I'm trying to combine these spreadsheets into one data set that I can analyze.  How can I write code that finds the data tab in each file based on the common columns?

Below is a simple example of what I'm dealing with

```
April 2019.xlsx
- tab 1 name "Summary"
- tab 2 name "data_apr"

may 2019.xlsx
- tab 1 name "Summary May"
- tab 2 name "may2019"

June 2019.xlsx
- tab 1 name "June 2019 report"
- tab 2 name "Junedata"
```

"Tab 2" above are the tabs i'm trying to combine in each of the files. The files have at least 4 common columns which don't exist anywhere else in the files and I think they can be used to identify the files that need to be combined. Although, the columns are not necessarily in the same order in each of the files.

Comment: Whatever solution will be provided, this is brittle design: your assumption is that no-one will ever create a spreadsheet where the columns you’re looking for are named on multiple tabs. Spreadsheets edited by humans will break that assumption at some point.

Comment: That will not be the case in this example.

Comment: (replying to the comment you deleted) Try to get access to the ERP directly?

Comment: will the columns always the the same, no extra or less?

Comment: yes. we'll be pulling through the same columns every time.  The actual data set and sample has about 20 columns and i only need about 4 of them in the consolidated report.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit, since you are looking for four columns in an number of columns we can use a set comparison to look at both of the lists of your master_columns and what the dataframe returns :

#### Lets import the relevant libraries.

```
from pathlib import Path
import pandas as pd

def col_matcher(master, df_cols):
"""
matches a list of pre-defined list of columns 
against columns in a dataframe.
if a match is found the then the path and sheet-name are passed
into a dictionary.
"""
    if len(set(master_cols) & set(cols)) > 0:
        print("Match Found")
        files[item] = sheet
    else:
        print("No Match")
```

#### read in your excels.

```
my_path = r"your_path" #path to where the excel files are.
# glob uses a wild match to find all excels within a certain folder/location.
xls = [x for x in Path(my_path).glob('*.xlsx')]
```

set a master column list

```
# these are the columns that we need to find in the excel.
master_cols = ['col1','col'2]

files = {} 
for item in xls:# iterate excels
    xl = pd.ExcelFile(item)  # load excel workbook
    for sheet in xl.sheet_names: # iterate sheets
        df = pd.read_excel(xl,sheet_name=sheet,nrows=1) # get 1 row
        cols = df.columns.tolist() # columns to list.
        col_matcher(master_cols,cols) # match columns and add to dict.

dfs = [pd.read_excel(x,y,usecols=master_cols) for x,y in files.items()] 
# our dictionary has our path as a key, and the sheet 
#as the value read this into a list of dataframes
```

#### Concat into a single frame.

```
df = pd.concat(dfs)
```

Comment: Thanks @Datanovice.  Are you able to add a couple comments to explain the code?  I'm having trouble understanding where to add in the excel file names and sheet names (if they are even needed).  Can you use the file and sheet names from my example.

Comment: @wolfblitza  added in a function to match the columns from your master list, all you need to do is change "my_path" with your own path to where the excel files are held.

Comment: the code seems to be working now but it's bringing in all columns into the csv instead of the ones I selected in the master_cols

Comment: @wolfblitza use the `usecols` argument to subset your desired columns. added to code..

Comment: the dataframe doesn't seem to be assigning columns but instead is treating the first row of data as columns

Comment: @wolfblitza I just tested and it worked for me.. not sure what you're doing differently?

Comment: I got it.  Thanks for your help Datanovice.

Comment: Happy to help @wolfblitza

Comment: are you able to add comments to the "def col_matcher" section of the code? I'm having trouble following.